# Stored procedure stops executing after few steps when executed from python

Tags: python, sql-server

I am calling a stored procedure from python using pyodbc from python. It stops executing after a few statements.

- Previously it wasn't reflecting changes in database. Fixed that issue using autocommit=True
- Divided steps into different two separate procedures and it works. Nothing wrong with the code
- I am using SQL Server 2017 RDS, couldn't find any time specific setting at the server that needs to be specified 
  It would be great to know reason of stopping stored procedure execution after some steps.

In the following script it stops executing from table3_trn processing:

```
SELECT  @l_cnt =  count(1)  
FROM   plutotrn.table3_trn

CREATE  OR ALTER PROCEDURE sp_load_data
AS 
DECLARE  @l_cnt  INT 
DECLARE  @def_schema NVARCHAR(20) ='dbo'
DECLARE  @transit_schema NVARCHAR(20)='trn_schema'
BEGIN  
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
 BEGIN TRY  
 SELECT  @l_cnt = count(1)    
 FROM   table1_trn 

 IF @l_cnt > 0    
 BEGIN   
    EXEC  sp_modify_indexes @table_name='table1',@schema_name=@def_schema,@enable_or_rebuild='DISABLE' ; 
    EXEC  sp_switch_partitions  @source_table = 'table1_trn' , @target_table = 'table1' ,@src_schema_name=@transit_schema ,@tgt_schema_name =@def_schema    
 END  


 SELECT  @l_cnt =  count(1)  
 FROM   plutotrn.table2_trn 

  IF @l_cnt > 0  
  BEGIN 
    EXEC  sp_modify_indexes @table_name='table2',@schema_name=@def_schema,@enable_or_rebuild='DISABLE' ; 
    EXEC  sp_switch_partitions  @source_table = 'table2_trn' , @target_table = 'table2' ,@src_schema_name=@transit_schema ,@tgt_schema_name =@def_schema  
 END

 SELECT  @l_cnt =  count(1)  
 FROM   plutotrn.table3_trn 

  IF @l_cnt > 0  
  BEGIN 
    EXEC  sp_modify_indexes @table_name='table3',@schema_name=@def_schema,@enable_or_rebuild='DISABLE' ; 
    ALTER TABLE table3  NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL ;
    ALTER TABLE  table3_trn NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL ;

    EXEC  sp_switch_partitions  @source_table = 'table3_trn' , @target_table = 'table3' ,@src_schema_name=@transit_schema ,@tgt_schema_name =@def_schema  


 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
   INSERT INTO debug VALUES (concat(ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_LINE (),ERROR_MESSAGE()))
 END CATCH 
END;
```

Comment: You have unbalanced `BEGIN`/`END` statements around your `ALTER TABLE table3...` statement block.

Comment: Its typo here .Procedure won't get compiled in case of unbalanced BEGIN / END statement.As I mentioned my code is working fine.Its just not executing all the steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by adding sleep time for 2 mins after procedure call from python and all steps from the procedure are executed successfully.May not be the best solution but worked for me.